# addEventListener only works once

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event listener. Inside it I'm looping through 3 images and applying style `translateX(350px)` to them. It works perfectly fine but it only works once.

I click right once and the images move to the right but if I click right again the images do not move. How do I make the Event Listener fire multiple times so images move multiple times? There is a similar question on Stack Overflow but I could not understand.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img class='move' src='images/news1.jpg'>
    <img class='move' src='images/news2.jpg'>
    <img class='move' src='images/news3.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id='arrow-left'>left</a>
<a href="#" id='arrow-right'>right</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
let imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('move');

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.transition = "0.5s";
    images[i].style.transform = 'translateX(350px)';
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want them to move further to the right or do you want to bring them back to zero so they can move to the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use an accumulator for your transformations so that they remember their previous translation state, e.g, 350 the first time, 700 the 2nd, ... etc.:

try this:

```js
var accum = 350;

let imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('move');


arrowRight.addEventListener('click' , function() {
  for (let i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.transition = "0.5s";
      images[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + accum + 'px)';
  }
accum+= 350;
});
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div class='image-container'>
        <img class='move' src='images/news1.jpg'>
        <img class='move' src='images/news2.jpg'>
        <img class='move' src='images/news3.jpg'>
    </div>

</div>
<a href="#" id='arrow-left'>left</a>
<a href="#" id='arrow-right'>right</a>
```

Comment: Hello for some reason it the images aren't moving at all it doesn't show an error i checked the code 2 times. could you try it yourself please.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/crmqj91t/15/
TranslateX takes the reference of the initial render position. So everytime you set translatex by 350px it remains at the same point with respect to its origin.

I've added a step counter, which sets the correct distance from the origin on each step.

```js
let imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('move');
let step = 1;

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.transition = "0.5s";
    images[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + step * 50 + 'px)';
  }
  step++;
});
```